# How to set the Timer Notification on reminder functionality in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, timer, notifications

I am developing WP7 application in .net. I am new to the WP7. I have developed a diary application on WP7. In that application user can select the alphabet make the entry of Income or Payment on the selected date. The details gets saved in the XML Files. Similarly I am adding the Reminder and Note in the application. Now I also want to add the time selection on the Reminder and Note. So that user can set the specific time while adding the Reminder and Note. I want to create some type of notification popup so that it will popup on that specific time of the selected date on which the Reminder and Note has been added. If popup will be a messagebox with some text then it will also be OK. Can you please tell the way by which I should go to resolve the above issue ? How should I set the timer in my application ? How should I display the notification popup ( or messagebox ) on that specific time of the date ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, I don't believe that the WP7 API provides apps with any access to the calendars or reminder APIs.

As a result, I believe the only way to do this type of functionality is by implementing your own web service for push notifications - e.g. see this [blog about how to show toast notifications](http://www.sgtconker.com/2010/03/article-windows-phone-7-push-notifications/) - and then relying on the user having a data connection at the right time.

Hopefully, a new API will get opened up in the near future.